# What does numpy's vectorize do?

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization, stop-words

I have a function for cleaning text of a set stopwords:

```
def clean_text(raw_text, stopwords_set):
    # removing everything which is not a letter
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", raw_text)
    # lower case + split --> list of words
    words = letters_only.lower().split()             
    # now remove the stop words
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stopwords_set]
    # join the remaining words together to get the cleaned tweet
    return " ".join(meaningful_words)
```

And a dataset of 1.6 million twitter tweet in a `pandas` dataframe. If I simply `apply` this function to the dataframe like this:

```
dataframe['clean_text'] = dataframe.apply(
    lambda text: clean_text(text, set(stopwords.words('english'))),
    axis = 1)
```

The computation needs 2 minutes to finish (approximately). However, when I use `np.vectorize` like this:

```
dataframe['clean_text'] = np.vectorize(clean_text)(
    dataframe['text'], set(stopwords.words('english')))
```

The computation finishes after 10 seconds (approximately).

That in itself would not be surprising, if not both methods only used one core on my machine. I was assuming, that with vectorize, it would automatically use multiple cores to finish faster and this way gaining more speed, but it seems to do something different instead.

What kind of "magic" does `numpy`'s ´vectorize` do?

Comment: Again, did you read the docs on `np.vectorize`? It states - `"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."`.

Comment: @Divakar How does that explain the speedup then? Even with the knowledge I cannot see how that explains the speedup, so that does not help me yet. Please keep it constructive, thanks.

Comment: Can you time it against a for-loop version?

Comment: Compared to explicit loops on numpy arrays `vectorize` typically shows small speedups (20%).  But you are comparing it to pandas apply.  Maybe thats extraordinarily slow when used like this.

Comment: Make sure that vectorize is working right. It may be feeding one stopword at a time to your function.  Check the shape of the output.

Comment: @hpaulj I checked, the result is correct, no more stopwords in the cleaned text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wondered how `vectorize` handled these inputs. It is designed to take array inputs, broadcast them against each other, and feed all elements, as scalars, to your function.  In particular I wondered how it handled the `set`.

With your function, and a `print(stop_words)` addition, I got

```
In [98]: words = set('one two three four five'.split())
In [99]: f=np.vectorize(clean_text)
In [100]: f(['this is one line with two words'],words)
{'five', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two'}
{'five', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two'}
Out[100]: 
array(['this is line with words'], 
      dtype='<U23')
```

The set is displayed twice because `vectorize` runs a test case to determine the dtype of the return array.  But contrary to what I feared it is passing the whole set to the function.  That's because wrapping a `set` in an array just creates of 0d object array:

```
In [101]: np.array(words)
Out[101]: array({'five', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two'}, dtype=object)
```

Since we don't want the vectorized function to iterate over the 2nd argument we really should have used the `excluded` parameter.  The speed difference is probably negligible.

```
In [104]: f=np.vectorize(clean_text, excluded=[1])
In [105]: f(['this is one line with two words'],words)
```

But with only one array or dataseries to iterate over, `vectorize` is little more than a 1d iteration or list comprehension:

```
In [111]: text = ['this is one line with two words']
In [112]: [clean_text(t, words) for t in text]
Out[112]: ['this is line with words']
```

If I make the text list longer (10000):

```
In [121]: timeit [clean_text(t, words) for t in text]
10 loops, best of 3: 98.2 ms per loop
In [122]: f=np.vectorize(clean_text, excluded=[1])
In [123]: timeit f(text,words)
10 loops, best of 3: 158 ms per loop
In [124]: f=np.vectorize(clean_text)
In [125]: timeit f(text,words)
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
```

`excluded` actually slows `vectorize` down; without it, the list comprehension and vectorization perform the same.

So if the `pandas` `apply` is much slower it isn't because `vectorize` is magical.  It's because `apply` is slow.

Comment: I get it. `apply` is slow and `vectorize` is "normal", so it seemed like `vectorize` was speeding things up, but actually it only brought them back to what they "should be" (which was a speed up). Thanks for doing the timings as well!